# Underscore fill in KDB

Tags: kdb

Is there another way to fill `_` to either left or right of the given string than the following?

```
q)a:"Apple"
q)"_"^rotate[5;a@til 12]
"_______Apple"
q)"_"^a@til 12
"Apple_______"`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$` operator](https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/DollarSign#pad) is overloaded to **pad** the string with `null(space)`:

```
q)"_"^12$"Apple"
"Apple_______"

q)"_"^-12$"Apple"
"_______Apple"
```

Comment: This solution would fall foul of strings containing spaces, provided they are allowed in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can append any string by using ","

```
q) (12#"_"),"Apple"
"____________Apple"

q) "Apple",12#"_"
"Apple____________"
```

Comment: Please replace (12#"-"),"Apple" with (12#"_"),"Apple" for shown output.